# Filtering dictionary value based on Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python dictionary with key and list of values. I m trying to get a value (r94 and r133) using regular expression:

```
dict = {
    'membersOf': [
        'AN=info-AB-A3ADD-Peasnasdd,AB=ancd,AC=b23b, AN=gcp.abc-34234- 
       uslk-pre.baddsd-jaksd-asa-r94,AN=adfd-BC-S3SDS-avdccd,AN=gcp.abc-34234- 
       werr2-pre.baddsd-jaksd-asa-r133'
    ]
}
```

From the dictionary values above I want to pick only `r94` from the string (`AN=gcp.abc-34234-uslk-pre.baddsd-jaksd-asa-r94)` and `r133` from `(AN=gcp.abc-34234-werr2-pre.baddsd-jaksd-asa-r133`)

Expected Output:

```
[r94, r133]
```

Comment: Can you please provide a valid data sample? I've tried to edit your code and as you can see from the syntax highlighting something is messed up. Using the name `dict` for a variable is also strongly discouraged, as it shadows the built-in name `dict`.

Comment: @Maurice sorry my bad. I've updated the dictionary. please look into it

Comment: It seems like the answer by @Subbu VidyaSekar already does what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

I used the regex starts with r followed by numbers

```
d = {'membersOf':['AN=info-AB-A3ADD-Peasnasdd,AB=ancd,AC=b23b, AN=gcp.abc-34234- uslk-pre.baddsd-jaksd-asa-r94,AN=adfd-BC-S3SDS-avdccd,AN=gcp.abc-34234- werr2-pre.baddsd-jaksd-asa-r133']}
reg = r'\br\d+'
re.findall(reg,str(d['membersOf'][0]))
```

Output:

```
['r94', 'r133']
```